# .NET MVC - Controller/View and physical path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to have controller/view for URL:

```
http://mydomain/SomeFolder/
```

And a similar physical folder to put files in it

```
http://mydomain/SomeFolder/*.*
```

Currently URL `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/`, only returns the physical folder is browsed if web.config allows it, but I would like it to return the view and `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/*.*` to return the files contained in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found, I whish I had found some simpler way though.

With this solution I still cannot put files in the physical path of `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/`, this folder cannot exist physically otherwise the controller/view doesn't work.
But what it will achieve is that `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/SomeFile.zip` returns the same file as `http://mydomain/**Content**/SomeFolder/SomeFile.zip`, which was my main goal.

I need to have two distinct routes for `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/` and `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/anything/file/etc`

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "SomeFolder",
            "SomeFolder",
            new { controller = "SomeFolder", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "SomeFolderSub",
            "SomeFolder/{*any}",
            new { controller = "TryDownloadFile", action = "Index" }
        );
```

`routes.RouteExistingFiles` remains `false`.

Then I have `SomeFolderController` that return SomeFolder's view.
And `TryDownloadFileController` that checks if the file exists in `http://mydomain/Content/SomeFolder/` instead of `http://mydomain/SomeFolder/`  and returns it.

(I guess if the file doesn't exist it should return some 404 response. Which would be `return this.HttpNotFound();`)

Comment: I'm unaccepting my answer because it looks like this only run SomeFolderController for http://mydomain/SomeFolder/somefile, and not http://mydomain/SomeFolder/[some x levels path]/somefile . I can't spend my time creating routes for every potential subfolder.

Comment: I just edited and rechecked it, it seems that it was only missing a *

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Let's suppose that you have the `~/SomeFolder/foo.png` file and a `~/Controllers/SomeFolderController`. All you need to do is to set the `RouteExistingFiles` property to true:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
}
```

Now when you navigate to `/SomeFolder` or `/SomeFolder/Index` the `Index` action of the `SomeFolder` controller will be rendered. And when you navigate to `/SomeFolder/foo.png` the static file will be served.

Comment: I think he wanted to know if he can create a `*.*` route or similar that will show the directory listing rather than the defined Controller/View for that path... I don't think it's possible :/

Comment: @Tallmaris: No, sorry probably my notation was confusing. Darin's answer looks like what I'm looking for (I will test it when I get back from work.)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, When I use routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; /SomeFolder/Somefile.pdf says "resource cannot be found". And also, has impact on CSS loading or not (kind of randomly) ...

Comment: The closest I get to the behaviour I want is using 'routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;' + having a "catch-all" route with a controller that will check if the file exists and return it to download (I only authorised sometypes of files in my code so .cs and config files can't be downloaded). It's more what I wanted BUT the results are unstable: some non-physical patch will load (controller/view) while others will display an error page (resource not found), and random loading or not of .css and .js etc.

Comment: And yet I have to check if it break the basics /index.htm behaviours that I use in some folders.