# Directory browsed instead of showing view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project on which I tested stuff related to this experimentation: [.NET MVC - Controller/View and physical path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650282/net-mvc-controller-view-and-physical-path)

Now I can't display a normal MVC view:

On `http://mvc4testsomething/Folder/Index` , the view is displayed.
On `http://mvc4testsomething/Folder/`, I get "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error.

Here's are ALL the current routes:
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Folder",
            "Folder/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Folder", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

`web.config` has:

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension" />
```

If I change `directoryBrowse` to `true` in `web.config`, it simply displays the folder content, not the view.

Than you for your help.

Comment: Move the Folder Route before the Default route.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you seen how Areas work in MVC? I think you need something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it. I had to delete the physical "Folder" folder.
But then I back to the start of my experimentation (the other question linked in this topic).